# Group values in nested dictionary by range

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary. This dictionary keeps the text ids and the repetitions of the words in those texts. I want to group these repetition numbers with certain intervals and keep the number of elements in the group in a dictionary or dataframe. I've included an example below. I tried many ways but couldn't do exactly what I wanted. Thank you in advance for your help.

Initial dictionary:

```
{938742158: {'car': 3, 'yes': 5, 'none': 6, 'bi': 5, 'new': 4, 'service': 2, 'color': 8, 'have': 6, 'back': 5}, 
 938735955: {'car': 5, 'my': 11, 'note': 5, 'dir': 3, 'led': 6, 'r': 3, 'line': 10}}
```

Target output:

```
{938742158: {'1-3': 2, '3-5': 4, '5-7': 2, '7-10': 1, '10+': 0}, 
 938735955: {'1-3': 2, '3-5': 2, '5-7': 1, '7-10': 1, '10+': 1}}
```

Comment: Why `938742158["3-5"] == 4`? How do you intend to create those groups? Why don't you post your best attempt, in order to start working from there?

Comment: I assume that the keys '1-3', '3-5' are supposed to represent ranges. If so, your expected output doesn't align with the input data. Perhaps you could say more about the algorithm used to determine how these groupings are made and also show what code you've written so far

Comment: 938742158["3-5"] == 4 because there are 4 words that repeat 4 and 5 times. These are yes, bi, new and back. These 4 words should be in the range of 3-5 as they repeat 4 or 5 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below

```
data = {938742158: {'car': 3, 'yes': 5, 'none': 6, 'bi': 5, 'new': 4, 'service': 2, 'color': 8, 'have': 6, 'back': 5},
        938735955: {'car': 5, 'my': 11, 'note': 5, 'dir': 3, 'led': 6, 'r': 3, 'line': 10}}
post_data = {k: {'1-3': 0, '3-5': 0, '5-7': 0, '7-10': 0, '10+': 0} for k, v in data.items()}
for k, v in data.items():
    for value in v.values():
        if 1 < value <= 3:
            post_data[k]['1-3'] += 1
        elif 3 < value <= 5:
            post_data[k]['3-5'] += 1
        #TODO add more conditions
print(post_data)
```

output

```
{938742158: {'1-3': 2, '3-5': 4, '5-7': 0, '7-10': 0, '10+': 0}, 938735955: {'1-3': 2, '3-5': 2, '5-7': 0, '7-10': 0, '10+': 0}}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much for your help.